# Monotouch Dialog TableView.CellAt(...).Frame returns incorrect position if table has scrolled

Tags: dialog, xamarin.ios

I am having a problem using RootElement.TableView.CellAt(...).Frame to position a popover on the selected row of a table created by a mono touch.dialog controller.

Fram.Y returns the correct position unless the underlying table has scrolled. How do I get the true Y position of a "scrolled" cell?

I have used this code before on a UITableView without problems. What is different about the UITableView that monotouch.dialog creates?

Full Code:
var popPos = rootElement.TableView.CellAt(rootElement.TableView.IndexPathForSelectedRow).Frame;

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add/substract UITableView's (inherits from UIScrollView) `ContentOffset.Y` to/from the Y position you retrieve from the cell. That contains the current scroll position of the the table.